# cordova open app from url - application error

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, webintents

i am trying to open my cordova app from external link like 
http://www.myurl.com/mypage and when the app opens it throw an alert

> Application error: the connection to the server was unsuccesful. (file:///android_asset/www/www.myurl.com/mypage)

i guess i need to handle the incoming url somehow, but this alert is coming right up.
tried to use "webintent.onNewIntent" and "webintent.getUri" but without success.

here is my code:

config.xml:

```
<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask"/>
```

android manifest file:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:host="www.myurl.com" android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

index.html

```
 <script>
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {

        window.plugins.webintent.getUri(function (url) {
            console.log("INTENT URL: " + url);
            //...
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

        window.plugins.webintent.onNewIntent(function (url) {
            console.log("INTENT onNewIntent: " + url);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }, false);
</script>
```

what am i missing?

Comment: Are the console logs in the two event handlers happening at all? Can you see the logs coming out? It sorta sounds like perhaps you have a different event handler somewhere which is handling this stuff and trying to open the URL as a file, is that possible?

Comment: no it doesn't.
the alert is popping before any of my page html or script are loaded, and even before the code in  [WebIntent.java](https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent/tree/master/src/android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out the problem...

i had another plugin [LaunchMyApp](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme) interfering.
removing it did the trick.